# What is Windows To Go in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-to-go

I know that Windows To Go is a feature in Windows 8 Enterprise. I want to know that what is it and how it works for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MS technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592680.aspx#wtg_faq_whatis).

> **What is Windows To Go?**
>
> Windows To Go is a new feature for enterprise users of Windows 8 that
>    enables users to boot a full version of Windows from external USB
>    drives on host PCs.
>
> **Does Windows To Go rely on virtualization?**
>
> No, Windows To Go is a native instance of Windows 8 that runs from a
>   USB device. It is just like a laptop hard drive with Windows 8 that
>   has been put into a USB enclosure.
>
> **Is Windows To Go supported on both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 drives?**
>
> No, Windows To Go is supported on USB 3.0 drives that are certified
>   for Windows To Go.
>
> **Is Windows To Go supported on USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports?**
>
> Yes. Windows To Go is fully supported on either USB 2.0 ports or USB
>   3.0 ports on PC’s certified for Windows 7 or Windows 8.
>
> **How do I identify a USB 3.0 port?**
>
> USB 3.0 ports are usually marked blue or carry a SS marking on the
>   side.
>
> **Does Windows To Go run faster on a USB 3.0 port?**
>
> Yes. Since USB 3.0 offers significantly faster speeds than USB 2.0, a
>   Windows To Go drive running on a USB 3.0 port will operate
>   considerably faster.
>
> **Can the user self-provision Windows To Go?**
>
> Yes, if the user has administrator permissions they can self-provision
>   a Windows To Go drive using the Windows To Go Creator wizard which is
>   included in Windows 8 Enterprise edition. Additionally, the Community
>   Technology Preview (CTP) of Service Pack 1 for System Center 2012
>   Configuration Manager includes support for user self-provisioning of
>   Windows To Go drives. Configuration Manager 2012 SP1 CTP can be
>   downloaded for evaluation from the Microsoft Download Center.

Comment: your answer is a copy+paste from technet, and that's plagiarism. Don' do that.

Comment: @Sathya fixed, accidentally hit the post answer button.

Comment: it's still a significant copy+paste. Adding blockquote is **not** the solution.

Comment: @Sathya So what is the solution as I have given the reference link, not saying that its my own written.

Comment: rewrite it/summarize in your own words.

Comment: @Sathya fixed again, check it now if it looks good.

Answer (score 6):

Taken from the Wiki after a quick Google search

> "Windows To Go is a feature in Windows 8 Enterprise that allows
>   Windows 8 Enterprise to boot and run from mass storage devices such as
>   USB flash drives and external hard disk drives. It is a fully
>   manageable corporate Windows 8 environment."

Source [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go)